# Play NSDATA into audio format IOS

Tags: ios

I have NSDATA which is recorded through AudioQueue , I want to play this audio through any AUDIO player on IOS, Please help on this.

Thanks 
Djrecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it as an audio file (e.g. WAV). AudioFile and ExtAudioFile APIs can help you write this.

You can't expect any audio player on iOS to interpret/guess a blob of sample data correctly. This is why file formats exist -- audio file formats can specify sample count, channel count, sample rate, sample format, and a ton of other information about the audio in the file. Using an audio file, you can exchange this recording in a format other programs are able to read (correctly).